# How to move tcolorbox's boxed title to place in front of the box?

Tags: tcolorbox

How to move `tcolorbox`'s boxed title on foreground (move to place in front of the box)? As you can see in screenshot (red rectangle, my highlights), the grid is overlap the title, this behaviour is unwanted.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\NewTColorBox{solution}{+O{}}{%
  breakable, 
    enhanced,
    sharpish corners, 
    colframe=blue!50,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=blue!50,
    parbox = false,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={Solution},
    attach boxed title to top center ={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    halign title=flush center,
    boxed title style={%
    colback=white,
    },
  boxrule=0.5mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  underlay={%
      \draw[help lines,step=5mm,blue!20!white,shift={(interior.north west)}]
      (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
  },
  lowerbox=ignored,
  #1
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
Some text
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can adjust the `yshift=` to suit your needs. `yshift=-15pt` for example should give you a result close to the shown screenshot.

Comment: @leandriis result in screenshot is unwanted, because grid is overlap a title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `underlay boxed title` instead of `underlay` the grid is drawn before the boxed title is added, resulting in the boxed title appearing in the foreground (see also page 200 of the `tcolorbox` manual):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\NewTColorBox{solution}{+O{}}{%
  breakable, 
    enhanced,
    sharpish corners, 
    colframe=blue!50,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=blue!50,
    parbox = false,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={Solution},
    attach boxed title to top center ={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    halign title=flush center,
    boxed title style={%
    colback=white,
    },
  boxrule=0.5mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  underlay boxed title={%
      \draw[help lines,step=5mm,blue!20!white,shift={(interior.north west)}]
      (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
  },
  lowerbox=ignored,
  #1
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
Some text
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```